# VBA: transform date to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to VBA and I have a sheet where the date in column E is formatted like this:

| Date |
| --- |
| 20230118 |
| 20220227 |

I want to write a code that transforms this to dd/mm/yyyy format. I've tried to seperate the day, month and year with the worksheet functions LEFT(), RIGHT() and MID(). But I'm not sure how to then use these to create the format I want in the exact same column for every cell in that column. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you sure that **it is formatted as `Date`** and not as text or as number? Please, check it and clarify the issue...

Comment: It is formatted as Custom, not as a date. That's the problem

Comment: Custom, custom, but it may be a custom `Date`... Is it formatted as text, or as a number?

Comment: @FaneDuru a custom number: ########

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, use the next function:

```
Function makeDate_(strD) As Date
    Dim d As Date
    d = DateSerial(left(strD, 4), Mid(strD, 5, 2), Right(strD, 2))
    makeDate_ = Format(d, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End Function
```

It can be tested as:

```
Sub testMakeDate()
 Dim x As String, y As Long
 x = "20230118"
 y = 20220227

  Debug.Print makeDate_(x)
  Debug.Print makeDate_(y)
End Sub
```

The value can be numeric or a string. The function can be used as UDF (User Defined Function) and call as a formula:

```
  =makeDate_(A2)
```

Or faster, placing the range to be processed in an array and return the processing result at the code end:

```
Sub testMakeDate_()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'the column where the custom Date/number to be processed
  
  Set rng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR)
  arr = rng.Value
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
     arr(i, 1) = makeDate_(arr(i, 1))
  Next i
  With rng
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        .Value = arr
  End With
End Sub
```

If your data is not in A:A, please adapt the two code lines `lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh....` and `Set rng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR)`, using your real column header...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Change_Date_Format()

   Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

End Sub
```